# get executing program directory

Tags: r

to get executing program directory

```
> pt=funr::get_script_path()
> pt
  NULL
> source("yourfile.R", chdir = T)
```

this code is not giving executing directory. it gives only

```
> source("yourfile.R", chdir = T)
```

How to get directory name?

Comment: Do you need `getwd()` ?

Comment: ``get_script_path()`` seems only to work when it is included within a script run  using ``source(path_to_script)`` or something like ``Rscript path_to_script``. This makes sense because if your are working interactively, the path to your script is not really defined.